# Assigning a probability function to a random variable such that its mean is $0$ and variance $1$.

Tags: random-variables

I want to construct a random variable $X_i$ which can take one of three values: $-1,0,1$. I want to construct a probability function such that the variance of this random variable to be $1$. How can I do that?

Note that $\mu=0$, and $\sum (x_i-\mu)^2=(-1)^2+0^2+1^2=2$. Hence, one such probability function could be $p(-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $p(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. However, that would mean that there is no probability of the random variable taking the value $0$, which is weird.

Comment: Are there any other solutions?

Comment: It is not particularly weird.  You cannot get a variance bigger than $1$ here, so  a variance of $1$ extreme and you should expect an extreme distribution

Comment: @kimchilover- I don't there are any solutions where there is a non-zero probability of the variable taking the value $0$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to start from the basic definitions. In your case, the probability (mass) function is defined by three numbers, say $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that
\begin{align}
\Pr[X=-1] &= a \ge 0 \\
\Pr[X=0] &= b \ge 0 \\
\Pr[X=1] &= c \ge 0 \\
a+b+c&=1.
\end{align}
You want $X$ to be zero-mean, then
$$
\mu=-1\times \Pr[X=-1] + 0 \times \Pr[X=0]+1\times \Pr[X=1]=-a+c=0.
$$
Also, you want the variance to be one, that is
$$
\sigma^2 = (-1-\mu)^2\times \Pr[X=-1] + (0-\mu)^2 \times \Pr[X=0]+(1-\mu)^2\times \Pr[X=1]=a+c=1.
$$
Putting everything together, the masses $a$, $b$ and $c$ must satisfy the following system of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a+b+c &= 1 \\
-a+c &= 0 \\
a+c &= 1.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
The only solution is the one you gave - but now you can ask yourself what would happen if $\mu \ne 0$ or $\sigma^2 \ne 1$ and play with the masses.

Comment: I suspect that in general that $|\mu| - \mu^2 \le \sigma^2 \le 1-\mu^2$ and if you have an equality then at least one of the points has probability $0$.